# How would I create an app for a website that does not have an API and uses ASP.NET?

Tags: ios, asp.net

Basically what I'm looking to do is to create an native interface for a website that does not have any sort of API. This would be a 3rd party app that would provide all the same functionality of the website, just optimized for iOS. The real problem I run into is in sending and getting user-entered data to the website as it is using ASP.NET which I am not at all familiar with and the user would need to log-in to the website.

This is kind of a convoluted question, but I am sitting at square one and not even really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking if you can create an iOS app that can interact with another website that doesn't have an API? If my understanding is correct, then there's really only one option I can think of.

You would have to make your iOS app make HTTP(S) calls to the ASP.NET based website and simulate GET/POST requests as if it were a "real" user. You would do this by using one of the native iOS HTTP clients (NSURLSession, for example) and would have to strip and parse the HTML you received back from the website in order to get the raw "data" required for your iOS app.

The situation you are describing is pretty complex and very brittle (you have to make a change to your iOS app every time any change is made to the ASP.NET website) and I would avoid this method of integration at all cost.

Comment: +1, you can probably use Fiddler to figure some of this out, but you will wind up spending a lot of time chasing updates. Just let the user interact with the site through their browser.